# $(...).selectpicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using bootstrap-select for a form. I include the scripts (jquery, bootstrap-select) in the header of the HTML file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet "type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

All the select elements with class "selectpicker" all called correctly. Example of the select element:

```
<select id="test" class="selectpicker">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

However, if I call the following script on the same page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#test').selectpicker('val', 'Relish')
});
</script>
```

I get this nasty error

> $(...).selectpicker is not a function

Looking at the sources tab in Google Chrome, I see that the bootstrap-select.min.js is loaded well. Has anyone got suggestions?

Comment: From their documentation you also need to include bootstrap itself: `Requires jQuery v1.8.0+, Bootstrap’s dropdown.js component, and Bootstrap's CSS` https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: Can you show a live example?

Comment: You need to include https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.5.4/bootstrap-select.js as well

Comment: Sadly, this was not the issue. Bootstrap was already included in the file (different HTML view).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you have another `jquery.js` reference that is loading after **bootstrap-select.min.js** it will wipe out `$(...).selectpicker` function and other functions. Make sure that bootstrap-select.min.js is loaded last.

Comment: This was it. Jquery was stupidly loaded twice in my solution. Thanks a lot, what a rookie mistake.

Comment: I tried this but not working..still says Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function @Djov

Comment: I found the solution .selectpicker() is working in document.ready()

Answer (score 3):

Try to load bootstrap before bootstrap-select ;-)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason this needs to be called through jquery

```
$("#MyDropDown").selectpicker('render');
```

This (non jquery) generates the error:

```
mdd = document.getElementById("MyDropDown");
mdd.selectpicker('render');
```

I'm interested to know why.

Comment: Hi, because SelectPicker is a jquery libray, it means that it will work & react only with Jquery 'objects' and not 'real' element selected from the dom, if you search better you can find that the elemnt returned by jquery ( using `$('#elemnt-id')` ) is far different from `document.getElementById("elemnt-id");`.

Comment: Thanks @HichamO-Sfh that makes sense.